# Main Thread processing issue

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios5, uiview, grand-central-dispatch

In my application i am using back ground thread for hitting multiple service and perform operation with core data. I have used main thread for back ground process ,Its working fine.
Here is my code

```
    dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(main, 
                   ^{ 
                       [self backGroundCall]; 
                   }); 

-(void)backGroundCall
{
   NSLog(@"Done");
        if([CacheManager refreshDBforFirstTimeUseWithDelegate:self])
       {
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"IsDBInitialized"];

            ContainerViewController *containerViewControllerInstance = [ContainerViewController getContainerInstance];
            [containerViewControllerInstance setUserId:_userID];

            [progressView setHidden:YES];
            [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            [self.navigationController setDelegate:containerViewControllerInstance];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:containerViewControllerInstance animated:YES];
        }

}
```

once i initialize the data base , i need to navigate to the container view.During the initialization i will display one progress bar. That is working fine, when the entire background process is completed(app is in minimized state). During the background process if i come to the foreground progress bar is not showing at that time black screen is display instead of progress view . After the completion of the main threat container view all not display[if i comes to foreground of main thread process].

[image]

i need to show the progress bar, if i come back to the app in the middle of the main thread process. Please guide me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Do your background processing in a background thread.  The UI cannot respond when the main thread is busy working.

Comment: Please give me some sample code regarding that. I need to show the progressView that i have returned in that code above.

Answer (score 4):

```
   dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(main, 
                   ^{ 
                       [self backGroundCall]; 
                   });
```

This is a bit misleading... You call the method `backGroundCall`, but you are actually doing this on the main thread. If you want to make some operation on a working thread, you can do this:

```
  // Declare the queue
         dispatch_queue_t workingQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
         dispatch_async(workingQueue,
                        ^{
                          // My background job
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                           ^{
                                              // Update the UI
                                           }
                                           );
                        });
```